# In Typescript, how can I define a class interface containing a property member that is a discriminated union type?

Tags: typescript

Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
export enum DISPLAY_MODE {
  MULTI = "multi",
  SOLITARY = "solitary"
}

interface MultiAssetDefinition {
  displayMode: DISPLAY_MODE.MULTI;
  items: string[];
}

interface SolitaryAssetDefinition {
  displayMode: DISPLAY_MODE.SOLITARY;
  item: string;
}

type AssetDefinition = SolitaryAssetDefinition | MultiAssetDefinition;

const assets: AssetDefinition[] = [
  { displayMode: DISPLAY_MODE.MULTI, items: ["a", "b"] },
  { displayMode: DISPLAY_MODE.SOLITARY, item: "a" }
];

interface AssetDefiner {
  assetDefinition: AssetDefinition;
}

class AssetHolder implements AssetDefiner {
  assetDefinition = {
    displayMode: DISPLAY_MODE.MULTI,
    items: ["a", "b"]
  };
}
```

The definition of `assets` properly asserts the types of the members of the array. However, in the class definition, the type checker complains that `DISPLAY_MODE.MULTI` is not of type `DISPLAY_MODE`. Here's a live reproduction: https://codesandbox.io/s/discriminate-union-class-interface-issue-8buqq?file=/src/index.ts

Am I trying to do something that's not possible with TS? Might I achieve this some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when you explicitly type the property:

```
class AssetHolder implements AssetDefiner {
  assetDefinition: AssetDefinition = {
    displayMode: DISPLAY_MODE.MULTI,
    items: ["a", "b"]
  };
}
```

For the other option:

```
export enum DISPLAY_MODE {
  MULTI = "multi",
  SOLITARY = "solitary"
}

interface MultiAssetDefinition {
  displayMode: DISPLAY_MODE.MULTI;
  items: readonly string[];
}

interface SolitaryAssetDefinition {
  displayMode: DISPLAY_MODE.SOLITARY;
  item: string;
}

type AssetDefinition = SolitaryAssetDefinition | MultiAssetDefinition;

interface AssetDefiner {
  assetDefinition: AssetDefinition;
}

class AssetHolder implements AssetDefiner {
  assetDefinition = {
    displayMode: DISPLAY_MODE.MULTI,
    items: ["a", "b"]
  } as const;
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good candidate for acceptance but the whole point of my interface is to enforce the consistency AND reduce the need for manually typing properties. I'd like to understand why typescript can't infer the type of assetDefinition.

Comment: Because you can assign to a class property whatever you'd like. If you assign something, that something can be later change and not conform to the interface anymore. You can either explicitly type the property so that it can not change anymore, or do the thing from the edit, but then you have to change the interfaces accordingly.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes sense, thanks for helping me understand your solution. I ended up using multiple classes for the different modes instead and made the property a getter so typescript knew it would always conform to the type.